# Nesting an array based on parent IDs

Tags: php, arrays, categories, nested

I've been stuck trying to figure this out for a week now. I have an array in the following format:

```
[
    1 => [
        'name' => 'Maths',
        'parent_category_id' => NULL
    ],
    2 => [
        'name' => 'Algebra',
        'parent_category_id' => 1
    ],
    3 => [
        'name' => 'Expanding brackets',
        'parent_category_id' => 2
    ],
    4 => [
        'name' => 'Factorising brackets',
        'parent_category_id' => 2
    ],
    5 => [
        'name' => 'English',
        'parent_category_id' => NULL
    ],
    6 => [
        'name' => 'Shakespeare',
        'parent_category_id' => 5
    ]
]
```

and I want to transform it into an array in this format:

```
[
    'Maths' => [
        'category_id' => 1,
        'questions' => [], //This array will then be filled with questions regarding each of the categories
        'children_categories' => [
            'Algebra' => [
                'category_id' => 2,
                'questions' => [],
                'children_categories' => [
                    'Expanding brackets' => [
                        'category_id' => 3,
                        'questions' => [],
                        'children_categories' => []
                    ],
                    'Factorising brackets' => [
                        'category_id' => 4,
                        'questions' => [],
                        'children_categories' => []
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'English' => [
        'category_id' => 5,
        'questions' => [],
        'children_categories' => [
            'Shakespeare' => [
                'category_id' => 6,
                'questions' => [],
                'children_categories' => []
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

So far I've been able to format categories that have no parents, but I for the life of me cannot figure out how to insert a category that has a parent into that parent's children_categories[] array. Here's the code I'm using, I need help figuring out what I should put in the "else" part of the foreach()

```
foreach($ids_as_keys as $category_id => $info){ //$info contains the name of the category, and the parent's ID (NULL if there is no parent)
    if(is_null($info['parent_category_id'])){ //There is no parent, so put it at the root of $nested
        $nested[$info['name']] = [
            'category_id' => $category_id,
            'questions' => [],
            'children_categories' => []
        ];
    }else{ //There is a parent, so search through all items (including sub-arrays, sub-sub-arrays etc.) until we find a match for the parent_category_id, and then add it into the children_categories[] array

    }
}

return $nested;
```

Comment: dont you  want to make a response? maybe accepting, or commenting ... :)

Answer (score 1):

I  tested this, absolutely works :

```
        $arr = array(
        1 => array(
            'name' => 'Maths',
            'parent_category_id' => NULL
        ),
        2 => array(
            'name' => 'Algebra',
            'parent_category_id' => 1
        ),
        3 => array(
            'name' => 'Expanding brackets',
            'parent_category_id' => 2
        ),
        4 => array(
            'name' => 'Factorising brackets',
            'parent_category_id' => 2
        ),
        5 => array(
            'name' => 'English',
            'parent_category_id' => NULL
        ),
        6 => array(
            'name' => 'Shakespeare',
            'parent_category_id' => 5
        )
    );
    foreach ($arr as $key => &$value) {
        if ($value['parent_category_id']) {
            $arr[$value['parent_category_id']]['children_categories'][] = &$value;
        }
        else{
            $parents[]=$key;
        }
    }
    $result = array();
    foreach ($parents as $val) {
        $result[$val] = $arr[$val];
    }
    print_r($result);
```

Comment: @Mohsen the above one is really correct answer i got different output. I don't know how it's nesting under the array. could you please add the output

Answer (score 0):

This answer is too close may helpful for you

```
<?php

$array = [
    1 => [
        'name' => 'Maths',
        'parent_category_id' => NULL
    ],
    2 => [
        'name' => 'Algebra',
        'parent_category_id' => 1
    ],
    3 => [
        'name' => 'Expanding brackets',
        'parent_category_id' => 2
    ],
    4 => [
        'name' => 'Factorising brackets',
        'parent_category_id' => 2
    ],
    5 => [
        'name' => 'English',
        'parent_category_id' => NULL
    ],
    6 => [
        'name' => 'Shakespeare',
        'parent_category_id' => 5
    ]
];

//data array
$data = array();

$i = 0;

//gothrough one by one
foreach($array as $key=>$value)
{
    //set the parent array
    if(is_null($value['parent_category_id']))
    {
        $data[$value['name']]= array();
        $data[$value['name']]['category_id'] = $key;
        $data[$value['name']]['questions'] = array();
        $data[$value['name']]['children_categories'] = array();

    //add the childrens according to the parent 
    }elseif(array_key_exists($value['parent_category_id'], $array)){

        //find the parent
        $parent = $array[$value['parent_category_id']];

        $data[$parent['name']]['children_categories'][$value['name']] = array();
        $data[$parent['name']]['children_categories'][$value['name']]['category_id'] = $key;
        $data[$parent['name']]['children_categories'][$value['name']]['questions'] = array();

    }
}

//display the result
print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using recursive function.

```
function insert_child($curArr,$childArray,&$parentArray){
      foreach($parentArray as $key=>&$val){
            if(is_array($val) && sizeof($val) > 0 ){
               if($val['category_id']==$curArr['parent_category_id']){
                     $val['children_categories'][$curArr['name']] = $childArray;
                     return TRUE;        
               }else{
                 insert_child($curArr,$childArray,$val['children_categories']);
              }
             }

      }
  return FALSE;
}
```

Where `$nest` is your input array

```
$nest = array(
    1=>array(
        'name' => 'Maths',
        'parent_category_id' => NULL
    ),
    2=>array(
        'name' => 'Algebra',
        'parent_category_id' => 1
    ),
    3=>array(
        'name' => 'Expanding brackets',
        'parent_category_id' => 2
    ),
    4=>array(
        'name' => 'Factorising brackets',
        'parent_category_id' => 2
    ),
    5=>array(
        'name' => 'English',
        'parent_category_id' => NULL
    ),
    6=>array(
        'name' => 'Shakespeare',
        'parent_category_id' => 5
    ),
);
```

code

```
$result=array();
foreach($nest as $key=>$val){
  $temp = array(
            'category_id'=>$key,
            'questions'=>array(),
            'children_categories'=>array(),
        );
  if(!in_array($val['name'],$result) && $val['parent_category_id']==NULL){
      $result[$val['name']] = $temp;
  }else{
         insert_child($val,$temp,$result);
  } 
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
exit();
```

PHPFIddle [here](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/014-62c)